# How to solve this iis error "couldn't retrieve the default document"?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-8.5

I deploy my website on IIS in windows server 2012 r2. IIS version 8.5

when I check the localhost. it throws this following error message

[image: Error message in localhost]

After that when i go to IIS default document. it is showing error like below

[image: IIS default document error]

**web.config**

I did not give any default document in my web.config file. I already publish before with out giving default document. it was working fine. because the default document, it will pick up from iis

```
<configuration>

<configSections>

<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
<sectionGroup name="devExpress">
  <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
  <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
  <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
  <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings>

<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>

         //here is my database connection only

</connectionStrings>

<system.web>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">


</compilation>
<httpRuntime/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
    <!--Added new line-->
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout = "600" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
<httpModules>
  <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
</httpModules>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="DX.ashx" verb="GET" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
   validate="false" />
  <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
   validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

</system.web> 
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v13.0"/>
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
<system.webServer>

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>

</handlers>
</system.webServer>

<system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
 </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

The above code is the web.config file.

**UPDATE**

> I found the problem. I already have already web.config file on my published project. When I try to deploy iis couldn't read all my code which is inside the web.config from my project file. If I remove it all my and give the default document = "default.aspx" alone, it is working fine. So how can I set with my own web.config file

Comment: Could you post your web.config as well please. Just make sure there isn't any sensitive information in there.

Comment: @Dale can you tell me which section you want from web.config?.  But I didn't give any default document

Comment: Can you post the whole thing?

Comment: The reason that I'm asking is that I think you have the <defaultDocument> in the wrong section, it should be in <configuration>   <system.webServer>

Comment: @Dale can you check now

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that's the file at the path in the pop up?

Comment: @Dale yes. why..

Comment: Are you using web.config transformation? Can you share with us web.prod.config?

Comment: @dale I found the problem. I already have already web.config file on my published project. When I try to deploy iis couldn't read all my code which is inside the web.config from my project file. If I remove it all my and give the default document = "default.aspx" alone, it is working fine. So how can I set with my own web.config file

Comment: @VictorLeontyev can you check my update now